# Pandas Drop first column Error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am using `read_html()` pandas function to read a html table and then finally convert it to excel using `ExcelWriter` and `to_excel`. But as my table has a index column so this is what I get when I use `read_html()`:

```
data = pd.read_html(url)
Output:
[   Unnamed: 0  1  3
0           0  3  5
1           1  5  6
2           2  7  2
3           3  4  4
4           4  5  6
5           5  6  7
6           6  4  8
7           7  7  7
8           8  8  8
9           9  9  9]
```

And when I do

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example1.xlsx')
data[0].to_excel(writer,sheet_name= 'Sheet1', index=False)
```

I get an index unnamed column in my excel files. I have also used `index = False` and `drop` function but it give an error as `Can't drop None`.

Comment: What is `print (data[0].columns.tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you need to remove column `0` and index use:

```
data[0].drop(0, axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name= 'Sheet1', index=False)
```

For check columns names if possible convert it to `list`:

```
print (data[0].columns.tolist())
```

Comment: This does the work. I wonder what am I doing wrong because I used `drop('A', axis=1)` . I thought it would delete column 'A'

Comment: So dont return `print (data[0].columns.tolist())` first problematic column name?

Comment: column list `['Unnamed: 0', 'a', 'b']` .  Now it says `ValueError: labels [0] not contained in axis`. So, I changed it to this `.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)`. Is it correct